# Are the JDBC Drivers for Databricks available through Maven (MVN)?

Tags: maven, databricks

I was able to download the SparkJDBC42.jar from here:

https://databricks.com/spark/odbc-driver-download/?_ga=2.197667436.2108403849.1597666739-906882328.1597666739

Is this driver available through Maven somewhere?

Maven is not mentioned in the documentation here:

https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html

http://www.simba.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Simba-JDBC-Driver-for-Spark-Install-Guide.pdf

Comment: Doesn't look like it's available on maven.

Answer (score 2):

I realise trying to prove the absence of something is impossible. However after extensive Googling I have decided they are *not* available.

[Checking MvnRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.simba) is not authoritative but they don't have it currently (Mar 2022)